# HtmlAgilityPack не удается получить переменные поля

Tags: c#, html, xpath, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Код с сайта выглядит вот так:

```
 <div class="store-rank" data-role="shop-rank">
 <span class="rank-num">2475</span>
 <a rel="nofollow" title="Feedback Score 2475" target="_blank" href="//www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/221743.html">
 <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/wimg/feedback/icon/23-s.gif" title="This is the Feedback Symbol for Feedback Scores from 2000-4999.">
 </a>
 </div>
```

Код на C#:

```
string result = "";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = web.Load(URL);
        HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='j-store-header']/div/div/div[1]");     
        result += node.OuterHtml;
```

Результат выполнения данной строки кода:

```
<div class="store-rank" data-role="shop-rank"></div>
```

Почему HtmlWeb не тянет всю страницу полностью? 
При изменении XPath на
`"//*[@id='j-store-header']/div/div/div[1]/span"` возвращает NULL.
При этом вот такое поле: 
`//*[@id='j-product-desc']/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li` с этой же страницы получается без проблем.

Comment: Чтобы проверить `HtmlWeb` тянет всю страницу или нет поставьте точку остановки на строку `HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode` и посмотрите содержимое `doc`.

Comment: HtmlWeb не вытягивает всю страницу, так как те данные, которые мне нужны получаются из JS

Comment: Может [AngleSharp](https://libraries.io/nuget/AngleSharp) лучше сработает? Там ниже на странице есть простейший пример. Я в свое время отказался от `HtmlAgilityPack` и выбрал эту.